# Message=Code: ErrorInvalidUser Message: The requested user '5f1fb9dd-2fc2-4f4d-8fa4-ebd144432b9e@eb0eeae1-e81a-4a23-a4e4-ca8688e0a18a' is invalid

Tags: email, send, azure-ad-graph-api

Sending mail using graph API from Azure function like below

await graphClient.Me.SendMail(message, true).Request().PostAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

Getting Error:
  Message=Code: ErrorInvalidUser
Message: The requested user '5f1fb9dd-2fc2-4f4d-8fa4-ebd144432b9e@eb0eeae1-e81a-4a23-a4e4-ca8688e0a18a' is invalid.

This (**eb0eeae1-e81a-4a23-a4e4-ca8688e0a18a**) is my Tenant Id but what is this (**5f1fb9dd-2fc2-4f4d-8fa4-ebd144432b9e**).

I am sending to a default user (AlexW@M365x270547.OnMicrosoft.com) which is already there in my tenant.

Please help , am I missing anything?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `graphClient.Me`, you need to get authenticated as a user. You can use [Username/password provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?tabs=CS#usernamepassword-provider). In this way, you can call the `Me` endpoint.

Or, you can use [Client credentials provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?context=graph%2Fapi%2F1.0&view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=CS#client-credentials-provider) to get authenticated as an application. And in this way, you need to use send an email like the following:

```
IConfidentialClientApplication confidentialClientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
                                                                    .Create(clientId)
                                                                    .WithTenantId(tenantID)
                                                                    .WithClientSecret(clientSecret)
                                                                    .Build();

ClientCredentialProvider authProvider = new ClientCredentialProvider(confidentialClientApplication);
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);
graphClient.Users["user_id_here, i.e. ab6d4cd6-fc2d-40c7-a676-f8773aebfb5f"].SendMail(message, true).Request().PostAsync().ConfigureAwait(false).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

Answer (score 0):

IConfidentialClientApplication confidentialClientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
                                                                    .Create(clientId)
                                                                    .WithTenantId(tenantID)
                                                                    .WithClientSecret(clientSecret)
                                                                    .Build();

ClientCredentialProvider authProvider = new ClientCredentialProvider(confidentialClientApplication);

GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);

string fromUserEmail =Xyz@M344x276547.OnMicrosoft.com

graphClient.Users[fromUserEmail ].SendMail(message, true).Request().PostAsync().ConfigureAwait(false).GetAwaiter().GetResult();